# Accessing variables in view - Django template

Tags: python, django

I am totally new to python and django. I want to know how to access the dictionary variables in template. I tried few ways but nothing worked out. if i print the variable in the template i receive from my view function this is what i get

```
{'BSE:INFY': {'instrument_token': 128053508, 'last_price': 1150.3}, 
'NSE:INFY': {'instrument_token': 408065, 'last_price': 1150}}
```

I want to loop through the `ltp` and print something like this

```
BSE:INFY - 1150.3
NSE:INFY - 1150
```

**EDIT**

For ex : in my template

```
{{ ltp }}
```

gives the output

```
{'BSE:INFY': {'instrument_token': 128053508, 'last_price': 1150.3}, 
'NSE:INFY': {'instrument_token': 408065, 'last_price': 1150}}
```

now how do i loop through them and print something like above mentioned ?

Comment: Can you post your views?

Comment: and `urls.py` file

Comment: @Rakesh updated the question

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for [**loop in the django template**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for).

**EX:**

```
{% for key, value in ltp.items %}
    {{ key }} - {{ value.last_price }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: .items is the thing i was missing here.

Comment: Glad it helped:)

Answer (score 1):

You can access any dictionary item into your django template as `{{dict.key}}`.

Suppose you have following dictionary in your views:

```
 dict = {'first_name':'first','last_name':'last'}
```

You need to send your dictionary item as follows:

```
 return render(request, self.template_name, {'data': dict})
```

To access your dictionary data in template, you can use

```
    {{ data.first_name }}
```

To iterate over dictionary, you can do following

```
{% for key, item in ltp.items %}
    {{ key }} : {{item.instrument_token}}, {{ item.last_price }}
{% endfor %}
```